# Magento 1.8 and varnish cache 4.0.5 get 404 product page issue randomly

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-1, varnish, 404

I have used varnish cache for awhile on my Magento 1.8. It worked well for a long time until now I'm having an issue that some product URL got 404 error. It's randomly, not specify any product. And the product worked again after I flushed the varnish cache.
Note that I haven't changed the VCL since the day the site started and The extension Nexcessnet_Turpentine was updated to 0.7.3. I updated all the magento security patch. 
What should I do to debug/solve this issue?

Comment: Have you applied some security patches recently?

Comment: I updated the latest patch and all other patches.

Comment: I firgured out the issue was came from magento core session...for more information, anyone got this issue should check this article https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/magento-1-enterprise-random-404s-on-the-product-detail-page-catalog-product-view